# POST won't insert values in php

Tags: php, html

Good day! I'm trying to save some data into my database and it won't work but it does not display any kind of error. please tell me what i'm doing wrong. I'm trying to find the error but I think another pair of eyes and brain could really help me. thanks! :)

this is my code

```
 <?php
 $user_name = "root";
 $password = "";
 $database = "db_tocode";
 $server = "127.0.0.1";
 $content = "content_temp1";

$uname = $_GET['username'];

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

$header = $_POST['header'];
$title1 = $_POST['title1'];
$content1 = $_POST['content1'];
$title2 = $_POST['title2'];
$content2 = $_POST['content2'];
$title3 = $_POST['title3'];
$content3 = $_POST['content3'];
$title4 = $_POST['title4'];
$content4 = $_POST['content4'];
$title5 = $_POST['title5'];
$content5 = $_POST['content5'];
$title6 = $_POST['title6'];
$content6 = $_POST['content6'];
$title7 = $_POST['title7']; 
$content7 = $_POST['content7'];
$title8 = $_POST['title8'];
$content8 = $_POST['content8'];
$title9 = $_POST['title9'];
$content9 = $_POST['content9'];
$title10 = $_POST['title10'];
$content10 = $_POST['content10'];
$content11 = $_POST['content11'];

if ($db_found) {

   $SQL="INSERT INTO $content (user_uname, header, title1, content1, title2, content2,                  title3,content3,title4, content4, title5, content5, title6, content6, title7, content7, title8, content8, title9, content9, title10, content10, content11) VALUES('$uname',              ' $header', '$title1', '$content1', '$title2', '$content2', '$title3', '$content3', '$title4', '$content4', '$title5', '$content5', '$title6', '$content6', '$title7', '$content7', '$title8', '$content8', '$title9', '$content9', '$title10', '$content10',   '$content11')";

header('Location:1stTemplate/index.php');

}   
else {

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);

}

?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: echo $sql and manually fire that query in phpmyadmin and check if there are any errors

Comment: @krishna — The table name is `content_temp1`. `$` indicates the start of a variable in PHP.

Comment: @krishna — No. PHP double quoted strings interpolate variables. Dropping in and out of literals and adding a pile of concatenation operators just makes a mess.

Comment: @krishna - You seem to be unaware of variable interpolation in PHP strings. I suggest you read the manual chapter about [strings](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 3):

Execute your query:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

and you are using localhost so your server name will be

```
$server = "localhost";
```

and use `mysqli` not `mysql`!

Comment: Thanks a lot. haha. I figured it out awhile ago! thanks for the help!!